# What is a curve? (Definition)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Studing for an introductory differential geometry course I've come across a lot of variations for the definition of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$, ranging from the most general one, admiting any continuous function on a real interval $I$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a curve, to very narrow ones defining it as a finite union of the graphs of regular curve parametrizations (or something like that). Do we have a real teminlogy issue, or there is some universally accepted standard?

Comment: Without further assumptions, a curve is any continuous map from $I$ into a topological space, or sometimes from $\Bbb R$ into a topological space. Sometimes there are further assumptions, such as a differentiable curve, piecewise differentiable, piecewise linear, etc...

Comment: Assumptions other than continuity are usually made explicit: $C^n$ curve, smooth curve, regular curve (which stresses on the fact that $\gamma'(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$ ), bi-regular curve (a regular curve with non-zero curvature), simple curve et cetera. These can be combined among themselves and with the "piecewise" relaxation.

Comment: Does $I$ have to be open? (Because I've seen that too.)

Comment: @Pythagoricus: No, it does not have to be open. For instance, "Peano curve" is a map of a closed interval. The reason for all this ambiguity  is that the concept of the curve is so old, at least goes back to 18th century. But one can ask similar questions about the word "number" (an even older concept), whose meaning (as the one of a "curve") depends on the context.

Comment: Also, "Jordan curve" is not even a map, but a topological space homeomorphic to the unit circle in the Euclidean plane.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$To flesh out the comments: There's not a standard convention/definition for a *curve*, because curve-like sets and mappings play such a variety of roles in geometry and analysis. The definitions below are not universal and definitive, but are intended to serve as a "cultural roadmap".

**Definition**: Let $(X, T)$ be a topological space. A (real) *path* in $X$ is a continuous mapping $\gamma$ from an interval $I$ of real numbers (with the Euclidean topology) into $(X, T)$.

Qualitative uses of paths include:

- **Topology**: Deforming one mapping to another (as in algebraic topology, where a path in a space of mappings is a *homotopy*, and under which quantities such as residues and winding number are invariant).
- **Smooth Structure**: Probing a space (as in the definition of a tangent vector to a smooth manifold as an equivalence class of paths; taking normal sections of a surface embedded in Euclidean three-space).
- **Differential Geometry**: Measuring a space (as when defining a topological metric on a Riemannian manifold by taking the infimum of lengths of paths; or carrying an orthonormal frame by parallel transport).
- **Kinematics**: Modeling the location of a particle or system state as a function of time (as when solving an ordinary differential equation).

These distinctions are overlapping and somewhat artificial.

---

*Technical conditions on paths*

- If $I$ is compact, the image $\gamma(I)$ is compact, which is often topologically desirable. On the down side, an interval is not a manifold but a manifold with boundary, and "differentiability" at an endpoint can be vexing (Note 1).

  When differentiability matters, one may assume $I$ is an open interval. Unfortunately, open intervals are not compact, and even a real-analytic path can be...pathological (Note 2).

  When one needs both compactness and differentiability, it's customary to assume $\gamma$ is defined on some compact interval $I$, but that $\gamma$ has a smooth extension to some larger open interval.
- If $(X, T)$ is a smooth manifold (i.e., is equipped with a coordinate atlas whose overlap maps are $k$-times continuously differentiable for some $k \geq 1$, or infinitely-differentiable, or real-analytic), one often works with smooth paths.

  Particularly in differential geometry, one usually assumes a path is *regular*, i.e., has non-vanishing derivative, so the image has a tangent line at each point.

  Very often when differential topologists and geometers speak of a *curve*, they mean an image of a regular path. (Thus, a *path* is a mapping, while a *curve* is a set of points.)

  For technical reasons involving concatenation of curve segments, it's often simpler to work with *piecewise-smooth* paths, for which the domain $I$ can be divided into finitely many subintervals, on each of which $\gamma$ is regular and the derivative $\gamma'$ has one-sided limits at the endpoints.
- A path may be *simple* (injective, i.e., not self-crossing) or *closed* (having compact domain $I = [a, b]$ and satisfying $\gamma(a) = \gamma(b)$. (In smooth settings, one may also assume derivative conditions such as $\gamma'(a) = \gamma'(b)$.)
- A path $\gamma:[a, b] \to (X, d)$ in a metric space is *rectifiable* (of finite length) if, letting $(t_{i})_{i=0}^{N}$ denote an arbitrary partition $a = t_{0} < t_{1} < \cdots < t_{N} = b$ and taking the supremum over all partitions,
  $$
  \sup \sum_{i=0}^{N} d(\gamma(t_{i-1}), \gamma(t_{i})) < \infty.
  $$
  A piecewise-$C^{1}$ path (on a compact interval) in a Riemannian manifold is rectifiable, but a continuous bijection need not be locally rectifiable at any point. [Note 5.]

---

*Notes and counterexamples*

1. The logarithmic spiral
   $$
   \gamma(t) = \begin{cases}
     e^{-1/t}(\cos(1/t), \sin(1/t)) & 0 < t \leq 1, \\
     (0, 0) & t = 0,
   \end{cases}
   $$
   is (uniformly!) continuous, and real-analytic in $(0, 1)$, but winds infinitely many times around the origin in every neighborhood of $0$.
2. Fix an irrational number $\alpha$, and define the *irrational winding* of slope $\alpha$ to be the curve
   $$
   \gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, \cos(\alpha t), \sin(\alpha t),\quad -\infty < t < \infty.
   $$
   The image of $\gamma$ lies in the (compact) torus $S^{1} \times S^{1} \subset \Reals^{4}$, and it's straightforward to check that $\gamma$ is regular and injective. The image of $\gamma$ is dense in the torus, however, and the complement of the image is fantastically complicated, being topologically connected, but having a continuum of path components. (The space of path components is closely related to the standard construction of a [Lebesgue non-measurable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set#Example).)
3. A smooth (even real-analytic) path can have non-smooth image if the path is not regular. Standard examples include:

   - The cusp $\gamma(t) = (t^{3}, t^{2})$.
   - The astroid $\gamma(t) = (\cos^{3} t, \sin^{3} t)$.
   - [Hypocycloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid).
4. If $I = [0, 1]$, there exists a *continuous surjection* $\gamma:I \to I \times I$, namely, a path [whose image is the unit square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve). Obvious iterative constructions give paths whose image is an arbitrary box
   $$
   [a_{1}, b_{1}] \times \cdots \times [a_{n}, b_{n}] \subset \Reals^{n}.
   $$
   No such path can be injective, since a continuous bijection whose domain is a compact Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism to its image.
5. The [*Koch snowflake*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) is the image of a continuous bijection $\gamma:S^{1} \to \Reals^{2}$. If $p$ and $q$ are arbitrary points, the length of either portion of the snowflake "between" $p$ and $q$ is infinite.

Comment: Thank you, this is food for thought! One question: you keep using the term ‘path’ avoiding talking about ‘curves’; is it just because ‘path’ has a more concrete definition? (The only variation in the definition of a path one can have is requiring $I$ to be compact, or even $I = [0,1]$).

Comment: In my experience, it's most common to say "curve" when one means a set of points (usually a one-manifold of class at least $C^{1}$), and to speak of a _path_ when one means a mapping or parametrization. Unfortunately, "path" and "curve" aren't interchangeable: The image of a "typical path" is not what one wants to call a "curve" (Note 4., particularly). <> The bullet points under _Technical conditions_ are all variations on the definition of a path, not just open/closed domain, but degrees of differentiability, self-crossing, being a "loop", or having finite length. :)

Comment: So, in advanced literature on differential geometry (not like the introductory course I'm attending) the meaning of terms like ‘curve’ or ‘path’ is either explicitly specified, or understood from context.

Comment: "Understood from context" is about right. Also in my experience, authors tend to be somewhere between breezy and careless about the definition of a "path" or "curve", slipping in technical conditions unobtrusively ("all spaces and maps are assumed to be of class $C^{\infty}$, though we never use more than $C^{2}$" in the middle of a lengthy survey paragraph, say), as if reluctantly trading simplicity of statements against generality of results and difficulty of proof. Again, my use of "path" and "curve" is not universal, e.g., Barrett O'Neill uses the term "curve" to connote a mapping.